# Calculate amount of final payment.

Tags: finance

i have a question for my math practice but i do several ways but i still get the wrong answer, please help:

Loan payments of `$700 due 3 months ago` and `$1000 due today are to be paid by` a payment of $800 in two months and a final payment in five months. If 9% interest is allowed, and the focal date is five months from now, what is the amount of the final payment.

I calculate by using future value formula: S=P(1+r*t)

The first method i try is:

700(1+.0.09*8/12) + 1000(1+0.09*5/12) + 800(1+0.09*3/12)= 2597.5

2nd attemp:

700(1+0.09*8/12) + 1000(1+0.09*5/12)= 800(1+0.09*3/12) + X

==>X= 961.5

Can Anyone help me? ( this is simple interest)

Comment: what is the right answer?

Comment: I don't know, that's the point. My teacher use a program and when i put my answer there, it tells me whether it's true for false, not the answer and i got wrong for both.

Comment: maybe the program of your teacher gives the wrong answer...your method 2 is right!!

Answer (score 1):

The focal date is the date of the last payment. At this date, the amount of the debt is
$$
FV_1=700\left(1+0.09\times\frac{8}{12}\right)+1000\left(1+0.09\times\frac{5}{12}\right)=1779.5
$$
and the amount of the repayments is
$$
FV_2=800\left(1+0.09\times\frac{2}{12}\right)+P=818+P
$$
We must have $FV_1=FV_2$ and then
$$
P=1779.5-818=961.5
$$

If you use compound interest, then
$$
700\left(1+\frac{0.09}{12}\right)^8+1000\left(1+\frac{0.09}{12}\right)^5=800\left(1+\frac{0.09}{12}\right)^2+P
$$
that is
$$
P=1781.19-818.14=963.05
$$

Comment: According to the post, the result \$961.5 is wrong.... Though the equations make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I instead would try:

- \$700 to be paid in 5 months,
- \$100 to be paid in 2 months,
- \$900 to be paid in 5 months.

Assuming simple interest (without exponential formulas), a 9% anual, and *liquidating first the oldest debt*, and carrying the values into the focal date, we shall apply again the interest over every paid amount:

- 3 months from the first payment into the focal date
- no months from the second payment into the focal date

Hence the final paid value with the focal date correction should be:
$\$700\cdot(1+0.09\cdot5/12)\cdot(1+0.09\cdot3/12)+\$100(1+0.09\cdot2/12)\cdot(1+0.09\cdot3/12)+\$900\cdot(1+0.09\cdot5/12)= \$1780.12$

From here the amount of final payment, at the focal date is:
$\$900\cdot(1+0.09\cdot5/12)=\$933.75$

**Note that** making a payment at the 3rd past month involves a factor of $(1+0.09\cdot 3/12)$. This is the *exact* amount paid at that instant. Carrying this paid value with a focal date at the 5th next month involves *a second factor* of $(1+0.09\cdot 5/12)$, so the final paid quantity have a doubled factor of $(1+0.09\cdot 3/12)\cdot(1+0.09\cdot 3/12)$.
Of course, this depend on the system applied.

Comment: I don't really understand, how can you get the $100, $900 and those months? And yes this is simple interest.

Comment: I am considering the oldest debt is paid first. Hence the payment of \$800 in next 2 months will cover the \$700 from last 3 months, and a partial \$100 for the \$1000 of today. And the remaining \$900 to be paid in the next 5 months.

Comment: Check the edit, with the correction of the value into the focal date. Because this is simple interest, it is different to apply \$700 by 5 periods and then 3 more periods. WIth compound interest, the original amount and their interest are reapplied automatically, and it is the same to write factors for 5 and 3 months than for 8 months.

Comment: I see your point now. It's quite confused at the first time because i think i can only use the amount of payment to calculate which are 700, 1000 and 800. The only fomula i have until now to calculate this kind of question is  S=P(1+r*t) so i was kinda confused with the way you expanded the fomula.

Comment: If the debt is two payments of \$700 and \$1000, and you pay \$800, you have to decide how the debt is going to be paid. You pay part of the \$1000 and keep accumulating interest in the \$700?. Or you pay the \$700 and part of the \$1000 with interest from today?. If you have similar examples, we could decide further.

Comment: I have a preety much the same example and i could do it right. However, this practice is quite something.

Comment: Which is the correct solution, by the way?

Comment: I don't know yet, because i only have 4 attemps and i already use 3 for this excercise so i have to spend more time to consider these results.

Comment: I insist one of the previous question from your guides will settle this question......

Comment: it turns out my second answer is the correct one but i have to put .50 instead of .5. Weird system.

Answer (score 0):

I use the present time as **reference date**. There are two methods with the corresponding equations:

$\color{blue}{\texttt{a) simple interest}}$

$$700\cdot (1+0.09\cdot 3/12)+1000=\frac{800}{1+0.09\cdot 2/12}+\frac{x}{1+0.09\cdot 5/12}$$

$\Rightarrow x=962.36$

The result is a little bit different from yours due the different reference dates.

---

$\color{blue}{\texttt{b) compound interest}}$

$$700\cdot (1+0.09/12)^3+1000=\frac{800}{(1+0.09/12)^2}+\frac{x}{(1+0.09/12)^5}$$

$\Rightarrow x=963.05$

Comment: In fact, the reference date should be the focal day( my teacher told me that), The focal day should be on the far right of the time line(3 month ago---now---next two month---next five month"al so the focal day"). So i think we should also use future value for $800 and X section, which is my 2nd method? Don't you think so?

Comment: @KTiger I have read over that the focal date has to be in 5 months from now. In this case your equation and your result with $X= 961.5$  is right. By the way, if you apply the compound interest method it doesn´t matter which day is the focal day. The equation remains equivalent due equivalent transformations.

Comment: That's the problem, However the system still tells me that i was wrong. There is a sentence in the exercise "round to 2 decimal places", i wonder do i have to make it 961.50 to get a correct result or not.

Comment: @KTiger It depends on how the system works. Mathematically the results are identical, $961.5=961.50$. I would try what you have suggested.